# 'code': 'SIGERROR' Validate signature error: * is signed by ** but it is not contained of permission

Tags: python-3.6, tron, tronweb

I tried to create a trx transaction on shasta network and passing correct private key using tronweb for python but it's giving this error

```
{'code': 'SIGERROR',

'txid': '44212bea170d07e2c83c5a4c1ba96e6617165474401f8af1e2a7f3c6f09257d6',

'message': 'Validate signature error: bc9d036b9f7f2a1d1b9688aafef323484b4bc0836faedb52168b4d6f47c780824840d8a9c3904863453b69e875f62106743aecf9d2c912d4911ca00839632aea1c is signed by TNBWAv3eDZ3W9c61etU34DEy2X1kx5v6m5 but it is not contained of permission.'}
```

my script is as follows

```
from tronapi import Tron
import json
full_node = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io'
solidity_node = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io'
event_server = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io'
tron = Tron(full_node=full_node, solidity_node=solidity_node, event_server=event_server)
tron.private_key = private_key
tron.default_address = sender_address
txn = tron.trx.send_transaction(to=receiver_address, amount=amount, options={
'from': sender_address,
'message': memo_text
})
```